# chain style + scala options

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I've got `configurer` that supports chain style like so:

```
val configurer = Configurer("init").propA("a").propB(3).propC("bla-bla")
```

it's 3rd party lib that I cannot change.

And I have my

> case class Config(propA: Option[String], propB: Option[Int], propC:
>   Option[String])

Now I need to build my `configurer` with given `config` object, the method `propX` should be called if corresponding value set in `config`.

What's the best way to do that in a functional way?

I don't like this

```
val configurer = Configurer("init")
val withPropA = config.propA.map(configurer.propA).getOrElse(configure)
val withPropB = config.propB.map(configurer.propB).getOrElse(withPropA)
val withPropC = config.propC.map(configurer.propC).getOrElse(withPropB)
```

Just feel there should be an elegant way.

Comment: This is a crappy API, just wrap this thing in a `fromConfig` function in the `COnfigurer` companion object and be done with it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with var, usually it's a sign of bad code in scala, but in this case I think it's absolutely acceptable.

```
def buildConfigurer(propA: Option[String], propB: Option[Int], propC: Option[String]) = {
   var configurer = new Configurer("init")
   propA.foreach(a => configurer = configurer.propA(a))
   propB.foreach(b => configurer = configurer.propB(b))
   propC.foreach(c => configurer = configurer.propC(c))
   configurer
}
```

Comment: If Configurer is a Java class then it most likely a mutable. If that the case 'configurer' can be val and use as: `conf.propA.foreach(a => configurer.propA(a))`

Answer (score 2):

Since you specifically asked about doing this in a functional way, I'd suggest using a fold on each option that transforms `Some` into the desired function and `None` into `identity`:

```
config.propA.fold(identity[Configurer] _)(a => _ propA a) andThen
config.propB.fold(identity[Configurer] _)(b => _ propB b) andThen
config.propC.fold(identity[Configurer] _)(c => _ propC c)
```

If you're really adventurous you can make this a little more elegant with Scalaz:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

config.propA.map(a => Endo[Configurer](_ propA a)).orZero |+|
config.propB.map(b => Endo[Configurer](_ propB b)).orZero |+|
config.propC.map(c => Endo[Configurer](_ propC c)).orZero
```

In real code you probably want to use Eugene's solution, though, since you're just wrapping an API that isn't ideal, and the important thing is being clear from here on out.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like @EugeneZhulenev's solution, but with `Option.fold` instead of `foreach` to stay immutable nevertheless (without going to the higher-order/scalaz version proposed by @TravisBrown):

```
def buildConfigurer(cfg: Config): Configurer = {
  val with0 = new Configurer("init")
  val withA = cfg.propA.fold(with0)(with0.propA(_))
  val withB = cfg.propB.fold(withA)(withA.propB(_))
  val withC = cfg.propC.fold(withB)(withB.propC(_))
  withC
}
```